# Is there a way to set variable to nil which are not matched in Pattern Matching, Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I wrote a plug which I want to use in two or more controllers.

For first controller there are two variables in params `%{params: %{“param1” => param01, “param2” => param02}} = conn` and for second controller there is just one variable `%{params: %{“param1” => param01} = conn`.

I used `%{params: %{“param1” => param01, “param2” => param02}} = conn` for pattern matching in the plug. And it throws `(MatchError) no match of right hand side value:` when a request comes to second controller.

I want a pattern match which will handle both cases gracefully. Is there a way to set `param02` to `nil` for **second controller** instead of getting an error.

Thanks in advance for your answer. I just started learning Elixir/Phoenix Framework and still new to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with pattern matching. You can instead extract `params` and assign `param2` within your code:

```
def foo(%{params: %{“param1” => param01} = params} = conn) do
  param02 = params["param2"]
  ...
end
```

`param02` will now be set to the conn.params["param2"] if it's present, and `nil` otherwise.